# Correctly mocking a class method

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking

Using the example in the [official documentation's Quick Guide](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html), I tried to implement mocking. I'm trying to mock the `vocalize()` method and have it return `"Meow, Meow!"`. Here is what I've tried:

```
import mock

class AnimalFactory:
    def vocalize(self):
        return "Woof, Woof!"

def build_animal_factory():
    a = AnimalFactory()
    sounds = a.vocalize()
    print sounds

def main():
    instance = AnimalFactory()
    instance.vocalize = mock.MagicMock(return_value='Meow, Meow!')
    build_animal_factory()

main()
```

Running this will output:

```
$ python /var/tmp/mock_test.py 
Woof, Woof!
```

I'm guessing that the mocked method only exists in the scope of `main()`. How do I get the mocked method to affect the `build_animal_factory()` function?

**Update**

Based on the linked answer, I got it working by changing the `main()` method to:

```
@mock.patch.object(AnimalFactory, 'vocalize')
def main(mocked_method):
    mocked_method.return_value = 'Meow, Meow!'
    build_animal_factory()
```

Comment: You've mocked the method on one instance, `instance`, not on `a`. Why not mock out the whole `AnimalFactory`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Supposing the `AnimalFactory` class is quite large and I only want to mock one method, how might I do that?

Comment: If you're only testing one method, why does it matter whether the others have explicit `return_value`s or not?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It doesn't matter, as I don't care about other methods' return values at this point. But I do want to correctly mock that particular method. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you, that was helpful :)